# Start ActiveMQ broker before Application

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, activemq-artemis

My application creates connections to the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis broker during application start, so the broker must exist before application starts.

I've created an embedded broker with the Holder pattern:

```
public final class EmbeddedActiveMQHolder {

    private EmbeddedActiveMQHolder() {
        super();
    }

    private static final EmbeddedActiveMQ embeddedActiveMQ = new EmbeddedActiveMQ();

    @SneakyThrows
    public static EmbeddedActiveMQ getEmbeddedActiveMQ() {
        if (embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer() == null) {
            Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationImpl();
            configuration.addAcceptorConfiguration("in-vm", "vm://0");
            configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(false);
            configuration.setSecurityEnabled(false);
            configuration.setCreateJournalDir(false);
            configuration.setCreateBindingsDir(false);

            embeddedActiveMQ.setConfiguration(configuration);
            embeddedActiveMQ.start();
        }
        return embeddedActiveMQ;
    }
}
```

Than I've created a test configuration:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class ArtemisTestConfiguration {
    @PostConstruct
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public EmbeddedActiveMQ embeddedArtemis() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("ActiveMQ starting!");
        return EmbeddedActiveMQHolder.getEmbeddedActiveMQ();
    }
}
```

And then I've attached it to my base test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "activemq.broker.url=vm://0?reconnectAttempts=3",
})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ArtemisTestConfiguration.class)
public abstract class BaseTest {
}
```

But the broker does not start and the message "ActiveMQ starting!" does not appear in the terminal, and the service returns an error:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'containerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
...
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
...
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApplicationContextInitializer helped me to solve this problem!
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/tests-context-initializer.html

I've created an implementation of initializer interface and moved broker there:

```
public class ArtemisTestContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        EmbeddedActiveMQHolder.getEmbeddedActiveMQ();
    }
}
```

And then I've deleted broker from my ArtemisTestConfiguration class:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class ArtemisTestConfiguration {
    @MockBean
    ArtemisContinualConsumer artemisContinualConsumer;

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate artemisJmsTemplate() {
        return new JmsTemplate(artemisTestConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory artemisTestConnectionFactory() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://0");
    }
}
```

In the end I've added initializer to the @ContextConfiguration annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "activemq.broker.url=vm://0?reconnectAttempts=3",
})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ArtemisTestConfiguration.class,
    initializers = ArtemisTestContextInitializer.class)
public abstract class BaseTest {
}
```

Now the broker starts before the application:

```
2022-12-13 13:58:19,742 INFO  o.a.a.a.c.server.: : AMQ221007: Server is now live
2022-12-13 13:58:22,474 INFO  o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.: : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2696 ms
```